# Python error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy

**Error -**

> Python error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis
> (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are
> valid indices

**NOTE -**
I suspect that the np.polyval has an issue.

**CODE-**

```
x = list(range(348))
x_data = np.array(x)
y_data = np.array(new_forces)
p = np.polyfit(x_data, y_data, 15)
yp = np.polyval(p, x_data)
fig = plt.figure()
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(yp, color='green', linestyle='solid')
ax.legend()
fig.savefig("graphsW2/"+str(hgain)+"-"+str(gain)+"-"+str(gaincalc)+"-"+"WForcescumul+P&L-"+p["symbol"]+ylindex+".png")
```

Comment: What traceback?

Comment: Traceback is poiting the fig.savefig() line, which does not make sense

Comment: what does 'p["symbol"]' do?

Comment: It gives the name of a ticker. I tried to change it a normal file name, same error. I removed line by line to find the line that causes the error and it seems to be the np.polyval() line.

Comment: You're poitning right, it's the savefig line. But I don't know why

Comment: ok, solved it. 'p' was used twice with different type. traceback was right. thanks for the support